# Intersection and Union of two columns in a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe of format given below.

```
movieId1 | genreList1          | movieId2 | genreList2
---------------------------------------------------------------
1        |[Adventure,Comedy]   | 2        |[Adventure,Comedy]
1        |[Animation,Drama]    | 3        |[War,Drama]
```

Dataframe schema is

```
 StructType(
     StructField(movieId1,IntegerType,false),    
     StructField(genres1,ArrayType(StringType,true),true), 
     StructField(movieId2,IntegerType,false), 
     StructField(genres2,ArrayType(StringType,true),true)
 )
```

I was wondering if there was any way to create a new dataframe with a new column which is the Jaccard Coefficient of two genres in a row.

```
jaccardCoefficient(Set1, Set2) = (Set1 intersect Set2).size / (Set1 union Set2).size

movieId1 | movieId2 | jaccardcoeff
---------------------------------------------------------------
1        | 2        | 1
1        | 3        | 0.5
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this input DataFrame:

```
+--------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
|movieId1|         genreList1|movieId2|         genreList2|
+--------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
|       1|[Adventure, Comedy]|       2|[Adventure, Comedy]|
|       1| [Animation, Drama]|       3|       [War, Drama]|
+--------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
```

with schema:

```
StructType(
   StructField(movieId1,IntegerType,false),    
   StructField(genreList1,ArrayType(StringType,true),true),    
   StructField(movieId2,IntegerType,false),     
   StructField(genreList2,ArrayType(StringType,true),true))
```

You can simply use an **UDF** to calculate the jaccard coefficient:

```
val jaccardCoefficient = udf { 
   (Set1: WrappedArray[String], Set2: WrappedArray[String]) => 
     (Set1.toList.intersect(Set2.toList)).size.toDouble / (Set1.toList.union(Set2.toList)).distinct.size.toDouble }
```

Use this UDF like follow:

```
 input.withColumn("jaccardcoeff", jaccardCoefficient($"genreList1",$"genreList2"))
```

to obtain your disired output:

```
+--------+--------+------------+
|movieId1|movieId2|jaccardcoeff|
+--------+--------+------------+
|       1|       2|           1|
|       1|       3|     0.33333|
+--------+--------+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much.